Grokking the difference between the memory usage reported by two different Grafana dashboards
I am looking at two Grafana Dashboards:

https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/14438-kubernetes-compute-resources-pod/
https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/15055-monitor-pod-cpu-and-memory-usage/

The first one uses the following Prometheus expression to compute the memory usage:
sum(container_memory_working_set_bytes{job="kubelet", metrics_path="/metrics/cadvisor", cluster="$cluster", namespace="$namespace", pod="$pod", container!="", image!=""}) by (container)

While the second uses this one:
max(container_memory_working_set_bytes{container="$container",pod="$pod"} / (1024*1024)) by (container)

The two graphs look more or less the same:
The first one (14438)

The second one (15055)

Also, the second one matches more or less exactly to what kubectl top pod reports:
mark@L-R910LPKW:~/hpa-test$ k top pod
NAME                                                 CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)
hello-kubernetes-hello-kubernetes-59ff45565f-q79hz   4m           419Mi
mark@L-R910LPKW:~/hpa-test$

I understand how the second expression works - pretty straightforward. But what does the first one show at all? It looks the same, but all the absolute values are much larger.
